# Bug Firebase sent event add_to_card with item_price

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I sent the item bundles with params from Google examples

```
val itemJeggings = Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SKU_123")
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings")
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants")
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "black")
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google")
        putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 9.99)
    }

    val itemJeggingsWithIndex = Bundle(itemJeggings).apply {
        putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.INDEX, 1)
    }
 
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM_LIST) {
        param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LIST_ID, "L001")
        param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LIST_NAME, "Related products")
        param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS,arrayOf(itemJeggingsWithIndex))}
```

and get results in the debug console like this:
[image]

Why can't i get a normal double price?

Comment: Share your reading place code as well.. that time only others can give solution

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to write the data. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, I used for the code the exact sample from Firebase events documentation. That is just mock bundle and firebaseAnalytics.logEvent which was added to onCreate for testing.

Answer (score 0):

*Firebaser here.*

It looks like the issue you've described is a known issue on our end. I've added another instance of the bug report to let our engineers know the growing numbers of the affected users. While our team continues to investigate this behavior, we've yet to provide details or timelines as to when the fix will be available. For now, I suggest keeping an eye out for updates on our [official blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) and [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for any updates.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer unexpectedly. it's not a bug, it's okay for debug mode. Detailed information can be found here: [Link](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/WGwCKEkdEOo)